# How can I hide the main tkinter program window whilst logging in using another Toplevel window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am practicing with a simple login system. I have a main program window which I wish to hide whilst a login window appears. When the correct password is entered I want the login window to destroy and the main window to reappear (deiconify).

The main program code (LibrarySQL.py):

```
from tkinter import *
import libraryentrySQL, librarydatabase, login
import sqlite3
import os



def click():
    entered_text = entry.get() #collect text from text entry box
    output.delete(0.0,END) #clears text box - start clearing from 0.0 (from line 0) to END (after last character)
    new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
    c=new_db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT definition FROM Dictionary WHERE word = ?", (entered_text,))
    for row in c:
        definition = row[0]
        break
    else:
        definition = "No word found in dictionary, try again!"

    output.insert(END, definition) #this inserts the contents of variable 'definition' at the beginning (END) - because it was cleared before, END is the at the start

def clickentry(): #this function is run when the 2nd button (entry is pressed)
    def definition_submitted(word, definition):
        new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
        c=new_db.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES (?, ?)", (word, definition))
        new_db.commit()
        new_db.close()

    definition_window = libraryentrySQL.DefinitionWindow(window, definition_submitted) #this creates the object 'definition window' and passes to it 'the window variable'
                                                                                        #so that it can have a canvas
def clickdataview():
    new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
    c=new_db.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM Dictionary")
    data = c.fetchall()
    count = len(data)
    database_window =  librarydatabase.DatabaseWindow(window, count, data)
    new_db.close()

def login_window(window):
    log = login.Login(window)



window = Tk()


login_window(window)

window.withdraw()

window.deiconify()


window.title("My Little Dictionary")

#Create the Label
Label(window, text="Enter the word you want defining:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

#create entry box
entry=Entry(window, width=20, bg="light green")
entry.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

#create submit button
Button(window, text="Submit", width=5, command=click).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

#create second label
Label(window, text="\nDefinition").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

#create text box
output=Text(window, width=75, height=6, wrap=WORD, background="light green")
output.grid(row=4, column=0, sticky=W)

#create submit button to open enter new definition window
Button(window, text="Enter a New Definition", width=20, command=clickentry).grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=W)

#create open database button to open database view window
Button(window, text="View Dictionary", width=20, command=clickdataview).grid(row=6, column=0, sticky=W)


#Create the Dictionary.db if not already present
if not os.path.isfile("dictionary.db"):
    new_db = sqlite3.connect('dictionary.db')
    c=new_db.cursor()

    c.execute('''CREATE TABLE Dictionary
    (word text,
    definition text)''')

    c.execute('''INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES
    ('Algorithm', 'Step by step instructions to complete a task')''')

    new_db.commit()
    new_db.close()

window.mainloop()
```

The Login class code (login.py):

```
from tkinter import *

class Login(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, window)
        self.title("Current Library")

        Label(self, text="Log in to use this program:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.userbox=Entry(self, width=20, bg="light green")
        self.userbox.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)

        self.passbox=Entry(self, width=20, bg="light green")
        self.passbox.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)

        Button(self, text="Submit", width=5, command=self.clicked).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)


    def clicked(self):
        username = self.userbox.get()
        password = self.passbox.get()
        if password == "password":
            self.correct = True
            self.destroy()
        else:
            pass
```

I know exactly where the problem is: the main window hides then reappears instantly due to the order of instructions in the mainloop.
How therefore, can I get the main to hide and the login window to appear UNTIL the password is entered correctly? After which I wish the login window to destroy and the main to reappear?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the `clicked()` method of your Toplevel instance to call `deiconify`, that way it's only called when the Toplevel is destroyed.

```
class Login(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, window):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, window)

        # this is the parent/root window
        self.window = window

        Button(self, text='show main', command=self.click).pack()

    def click(self):

        self.destroy()          # destroy the toplevel
        self.window.deiconify() # and restore the root window
```

And in your main module:

```
root = Tk()

# make the login instance
Login(root)

# withdraw the main window
root.withdraw()

# set up widgets in main window
...

mainloop()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I'm pleased I wasn't that far away from the answer. May I just ask about the change in name from window to root? Is this just convention to keep track of which window is the main one and which are the children (objects created from the main window)?

Comment: Yes, it's mainly convention, you can use whatever is easier. Sometimes `root` is a convention for another module, so it might be confusing for someone else looking at your code, so whatever is most clear is what I go for.